# Run two infinite loop at once in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have programmed a langton's ant and it work nice.

Now I want to run 2 ant simultaneously.I have a run function how make the computation and ant's movement and it's a infinite run loop.

How can I run 2 of this loop at once ?

I have try to look on Thread but i'm not sure that it's the best for my case.

This is some example of my code :

Run function :

```
let run(f,tab2 : t_fourmi*int array array) = 
  f.xx := !(f.x);
  f.yy := !(f.y);
  let d = ref 0
  and z = ref 0
  and o = ref 0
  (* 1 = de bas, 2 = de droite, 3 = de haut, 4 = de gauche *) 
  in
  if tab2.(!(f.x)/5).(!(f.y)/5) = 0
  then move_right(f,1,tab2);
  if !(f.xx) + 5 = !(f.x)
  then d := 4
  else if !(f.xx) - 5 = !(f.x)
  then d := 2
  else if !(f.yy) + 5 = !(f.y)
  then d := 1
  else if !(f.yy) - 5 = !(f.y)
  then d := 3;

  while true
  do
  (*
  print_string "step : ";
  print_int !o;
  print_newline(); *)
  o := !o + 1;
  f.xx := !(f.x);
  f.yy := !(f.y);
  z := tab2.(!(f.x)/5).(!(f.y)/5);
  if !z = 0 
  then move_right(f,!d,tab2)
  else if !z = 1
  then move_left(f,!d,tab2)
  else if !z = 2 
  then move_right(f,!d,tab2)
  else if !z = 3 
  then move_right(f,!d,tab2);
  if !(f.xx) + 5 = !(f.x)
  then d := 4
  else if !(f.xx) - 5 = !(f.x)
  then d := 2
  else if !(f.yy) + 5 = !(f.y)
  then d := 1
  else if !(f.yy) - 5 = !(f.y)
  then d := 3;
  done;
;;
```

Example of move function :

```
let move_left(f,d,tab2 : t_fourmi*int*int array array) = (* d = direction d'ou la fourmi viens *)
(* 1 = de bas, 2 = de droite, 3 = de haut, 4 = de gauche *) 
  f.xx := !(f.x);
  f.yy := !(f.y);
  if d = 1 
  then f.x := !(f.x) - 5
  else if d = 2
  then f.y := !(f.y) - 5
  else if d = 3
  then f.x := !(f.x) + 5
  else if d = 4
  then f.y := !(f.y) + 5;
  if !(f.x) >= 995
  then f.x := 5
  else if !(f.x) <= 5
  then f.x := 995;
  if !(f.y) >= 995
  then f.y := 5
  else if !(f.y) <= 5
  then f.y := 995;
  create_fourmi(f);
  let n = tab2.(!(f.xx)/5).(!(f.yy)/5) in
  drawinv(!(f.xx),!(f.yy),n,tab2);
;;
```

If you need more function, ask me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "at once"? Do you mean to run them simultaneously? On separate cores? If so, why? Are these calculations extremely heavy and time-sensitive? If you show some code and explain what you've tried it might be easier to help you.

Comment: Your question is poorly written and no proof of an actual work provided, please edit it to show what you made.

Comment: Okey sorry, I will edit my post, @Glennsl I want to run them timultaneously

Comment: That is extremely imperative... Are you sure you should be using OCaml for this? It's much easier to write C in C. Or Go. Also, are you sure you need them to run them independently, or do you just need them to run at the same time? Can you change the implementation of `run` freely? If so you can refactor this into a couple of functions and extract the state and looping in order to step through each of them one after the other in an external loop.

Comment: Mm okey I will try whay you propose. I'm training with Ocaml because it's my school's programming language

Comment: The code you provide is not complete. I can’t test it because you are missing a definition of the type `t_fourmi`. There are several ways this code can be improved to make the changes you want easier: 1. Change the `t_fourmi` type to have mutable fields instead of `ref`s; 2. Make none of the fields mutable or refs and instead create a new value after each iteration; 3. Create a variant type for your direction, `d` instead of using some ints; 4. Convert the body of your while loop to a function `int array array -> t_fourmi -> t_fourmi`; 5. Now you should be able to use @glennsl’s answer.

Comment: It’s not clear what “simultaneously” means. I think you mean repeated steps of “ant1 moves, ant2 moves”, ie the ants move at exactly the same speed and it is well defined what happens if they collide. But maybe I’m wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly (it's unfortunately not very readable), it could be outlined as essentially:

```ml
let init params =
  ...

let step state =
   ...

let move thing state =
   ...

let run params thing =
  let state = ref (init params) in
  while true do
    let state := step state in
    move thing state
  done
```

where I've factored `init`, `step` and `move` out into separate function, which should be pretty straight-forward to do. And by doing so we can replace the `run` function with a `run_two` function that can run two instances *virtually* at the same time, though not entirely in parallel. They won't run independently, but in synchrony, iteration by iteration:

```ml
let run_two params1 thing1 params2 thing2 =
  let state1 = ref (init params1) in
  let state2 = ref (init params2) in
  while true do
    state1 := step !state1;
    state2 := step !state2;
    move !state1;
    move !state2;
  done
```

This doesn't use any threads or other complicated concurrency primitives. It's just ordinary code organized in a way that allows composition. It also allows the `init` and `step` function to be completely pure, which makes them easy to test and reason about. You could even make the `move` functions pure, if you factor out the drawing.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm sorry but I don't understand why my program isn't readable ? I write this program like I have learn in my school.

Comment: The code lacks structure, such as separating into functions like I suggested in my answer, which makes it difficult to try to understand the code in parts because everything can access everything else and anything can be used and changed from anywhere. It uses mutation unnecessarily, which is bad because the value might change at any time and compounds the problem of lacking structure. The variable names are not descriptive, which makes it hard to remember what they refer to, and you use integer values instead of variants, which suffers the same problem. You also use a lot of magic numbers.

Comment: Okey, I thank you for your advice. I will try to enforce that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads, though it will open a pandora box for you. You have to synchronize your ants, since probably you want them to move in the same world.

## Running two ants in different threads

First of all, you have to represent each ant process as an ever-looping function of type `ant -> unit`, where `ant` is the type that describes ant's initial position, moving parameters, and so on (if you don't need this, then just use `unit` instead. So suppose we have a function `val run : ant -> unit`. Next, we need to make sure, that we do not write to the same board at the same time from different threads, so we need to create a mutex, using [Mutex.create](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Mutex.html#VALcreate), we then need to update our run function and do [Mutex.lock](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Mutex.html#VALlock) before updating our board, and [Mutex.unlock](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Mutex.html#VALunlock) after. Finally, we should ensure that no ants will starve for the board, and that once an ant finishes it moves it yields the control to another ant, we could do this using [Thread.delay](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Thread.html#VALdelay) if we want our simulation to be smooth (i.e., if we want to artificially slow it down to human-observable speed). Otherwise, we can just use [Thread.yield](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Thread.html#VALyield). (Note, normally threads are preempted (forced to yield) by the system, but this is done in special yield points. When we do system programming there are usually lots of yield points, but this is not our case, so we have to implement this cooperation explicitly). Finally, our updated run function is ready to be run in a thread, with [Thread.create](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Thread.html#VALrun)`run ant`. This function will return to our main thread of execution, so we can run a second `ant` and so on. Once all ants start running we have to call [Thread.join](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Thread.html#VALjoin) to wait for all of them. Ideally, this function should never return.

I hope, that the above outline provided enough information for you, and you can enjoy the coding yourself. Feel free to ask questions int the comment section if anything is unclear. Probably, the first question would be how to compile it. It is (there are simpler ways, of course, but the most basic is, assuming that your program is in the `ant.ml`):

```
ocamlopt -thread unix.cmxa threads.cmxa ant.ml -o ant
```

## Running two ants in co-routines

While the above will work, it seems too complicated and too system-dependent for such a simple simulation task. Why do we need to use system threads for that? We actually don't, we can be clever and implement co-routines using plain OCaml and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). Don't worry, a continuation is just a function. And a continuation-passing style is when we are calling another function at the end of the other function. In this approach, we will not have the `run` function that runs infinitely, instead, we will have a `step` function that advances an ant one step forward at each invocation. For the demonstration purposes, let's simplify our `step` function so that each ant just greets another, e.g.,

```
let step other yield =
  print_endline ("Hello, " ^ other);
  yield ()
```

That simple. We do our step, and then call the `yield` function (that is that fancy *continuation*) to yield the control to the next ant. Now let's tie it together in a simple infinite loop, e.g.,

```
let rec loop () =
  step "Joe" @@ fun () ->
  step "Doe" @@ fun () ->
  loop ()

let () = loop ()
```

Let's make it clear. `step "Joe" @@ fun () -> <continue>` is the same as `step "Joe" (fun () -> <continue>)`, and this `(fun () -> <continue>)` is the yield function that is passed to the `step` function that greets Joe. Once Joe is greeted the step function calls us again and we evaluate the `<continue>`, which is, in our case `step "Doe" @@ fun () -> loop ()`, i.e., we pass the `fun () -> loop ()` function as the `yield` argument to the `step` function that greets Doe, so once Doe is greeted, we call `loop ()` ... and now we're at the begining of the loop.

In our case, we were passing a value of type `unit` in our continuations, but we can also pass an arbitrary value, e.g., a value that will represent the state of our simulation (the board with ant positions). This will enable a functional implementation of your simulation if you want to try it.